# How to include dependencies for QT application on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, dependencies

I'm developing a QT application that is intended to run only on Linux. I need to install some additional packages, and would like it to do so offline.

So far I've installed the packages using a QProcess like so:
    `process.start("pkexec", QStringList() << "--user" << "root" << "apt-get" << "install" << "[package]");`
But this is not how i intended it to be in the end.

Instead i want to pack the needed packages in a resource file and run them from there.

I tried to put the packages in a resource file, and running it from there with the use of a process. But this didn't work, maybe due to that the resource file is read only?
`process.start("pkexec", QStringList() << "--user" << "root" << "apt-get" << "install" << ":/packages/[package]" );`

Comment: You would need to extract the data from your resource file to your OS before running apt-get. Your package manager does not know how to extract a Qt resource directly from a binary.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you, it worked!